# Lazy variable lookup in Jinja templates

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I want to render a Jinja2 Template using a custom object implementing the `__getitem__` interface. The object implements a lazy variable look up because it is impossible to create a dictionary from it (the number of available variables is almost infinite, value retrieval works dynamically on the queried key).

Is it possible to render a Jinja2 template using a context object?

```
# Invalid code, but I'd like to have such an interface.
#

from jinja2 import Template

class Context(object):

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        # Create a value dynamically based on `name`
        if name.startswith('customer'):
             key = name[len('customer_'):]
             return getattr(get_customer(), key)
        raise KeyError(name)

t = Template('Dear {{ customer_first }},\n')
t.render(Context())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now figured out this (extremely hacky and ugly) solution.

```
t = CustomTemplate(source)
t.set_custom_context(Context())
print t.render()
```

Using the following replacements:

```
from jinja2.environment import Template as JinjaTemplate
from jinja2.runtime import Context as JinjaContext

class CustomContextWrapper(JinjaContext):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomContextWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__custom_context = None

    def set_custom_context(self, custom_context):
        if not hasattr(custom_context, '__getitem__'):
            raise TypeError('custom context object must implement __getitem__()')
        self.__custom_context = custom_context

    # JinjaContext overrides

    def resolve(self, key):
        if self.__custom_context:
            try:
                return self.__custom_context[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return super(CustomContextWrapper, self).resolve(key)

class CustomTemplate(JinjaTemplate):

    def set_custom_context(self, custom_context):
        self.__custom_context = custom_context

    # From jinja2.environment (2.7), modified
    def new_context(self, vars=None, shared=False, locals=None,
                    context_class=CustomContextWrapper):
        context = new_context(self.environment, self.name, self.blocks,
                              vars, shared, self.globals, locals,
                              context_class=context_class)
        context.set_custom_context(self.__custom_context)
        return context

# From jinja2.runtime (2.7), modified
def new_context(environment, template_name, blocks, vars=None,
                shared=None, globals=None, locals=None,
                context_class=CustomContextWrapper):
    """Internal helper to for context creation."""
    if vars is None:
        vars = {}
    if shared:
        parent = vars
    else:
        parent = dict(globals or (), **vars)
    if locals:
        # if the parent is shared a copy should be created because
        # we don't want to modify the dict passed
        if shared:
            parent = dict(parent)
        for key, value in iteritems(locals):
            if key[:2] == 'l_' and value is not missing:
                parent[key[2:]] = value
    return context_class(environment, parent, template_name, blocks)
```

Can anyone offer a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a function, `get_customer()` which returns a dictionary, or is an object?

Why not just pass that to the template?

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = Template('Dear {{ customer.first }},\n')
t.render(customer=get_customer())
```

IIRC, Jinja is pretty forgiving of keys that don't exist, so `customer.bogus_key` shouldn't crash.

Comment: `get_customer()` returns an object, which is why I use `getattr()` to obtain the attribute `key` which would be `'first'`. The example I showed above is just so that people can see what I'm trying to do. Maybe not chosen wisely since this example would really be the same as writing `customer.first` instead of `customer_first`. In real, I just want to compute a value based on a key. It's not possible/effective to put them into one dictionary.

Comment: Hrm. I guess I'm confused why you can't pass the object to the template and access it's keys there.

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of digging I found out the cleanest way to do this.

First create a subclass of `jinja2.runtime.Context` that implements `resolve_or_missing` ([docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.runtime.Context.resolve_or_missing)):

```py
from jinja2.runtime import Context


class MyContext(Context):
  """A custom jinja2 context class."""

  def resolve_or_missing(self, key):
    # TODO(you): Add your custom behavior here
    return super(TrackingContext, self).resolve_or_missing(key)
```

Then all you need to do is set the `context_class` variable of the Jinja Environment ([docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/?highlight=context_class#jinja2.Environment.context_class))

```py
env.context_class = MyContext
```

I was using Flask so I did this:

```py
flask.current_app.jinja_environment.context_class = MyContext
```

Comment: Way cleaner than the accepted answer, thanks!